# Use of the assignment where values are missing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, variable-assignment

Below is the simple program that I have copied from a learning website to test 'NaN' values. I am not sure what is the use of the assignment i.e. missing = np.nan.The program runs without no issues if I omit this assignment.

```
import numpy as np

from pandas import Series, DataFrame

missing = np.nan

ser1 = Series (['row1',missing,'row3','row4',missing,'row6','row7',missing,'row9'])

ser1
```

Answer (score 0):

np.nan gives nan value to the variable nan.

```
import numpy as np
missing = np.nan
print(missing)
```

ouput> nan

So you are basically adding a missing (nan value/no value/void value) in your series.

The idea here is to teach you (by that learning website) how to create series with nan value. As nan values are very common in real-life datasets and we must know how to treat them.